# Coinvariants of Tensor Product of $G$-Modules

Tags: group-theory, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a group, and for a $G$-module $A$, denote by $A_G$ the group of coinvariants (i.e., $A_G = \mathbb{Z} \otimes_G A$). In Atiyah's group cohomology text, the following claim is made: for $G$-modules $A,B$, we have
$$(A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B)_G \simeq A \otimes_G B,$$
where I the identification is, I presume, one of $G$-modules. But this appears to be false: the action of $G$ on the LHS (the coinvariants) is trivial, whereas the action on the RHS is nontrivial.

Am I correct to say that the above is just a typo, and that the authors probably meant to write
$$(A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B)_G \simeq A_G \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B_G?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The identification is as abelian groups. $A \otimes_G B$ does not mean the tensor product you might be familiar with from representation theory; it means the LHS. The second statement you write is false.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response, but I'm not sure how to reconcile your definition of $A \otimes_G B$ with Atiyah's definition, which is the tensor product of the $G$-modules $A$ and $B$ over the group ring $\mathbb{Z}[G]$. Do you mean that I am not to regard $A \otimes_G B$ as a $G$-module? That would be strange because Atiyah seems happy to regard $A_G = \mathbb{Z} \otimes_G A$ as a $G$-module.

Comment: @Ashvin: that is the definition that I have in mind, but the result of doing that is an abelian group. What $G$-module structure do you have in mind?

Comment: Perhaps I'm being silly, but I just thought the action of $G$ was given by $g(a \otimes b) = (ga) \otimes b = a \otimes (gb)$ for each $g \in G$. It seems like this $G$-action is nontrivial, whereas $(A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B)_G$ is a group of coinvariants and must therefore have a trivial $G$-action. Am I making a mistake here?

Comment: @Ashwin: in order to define $A \otimes_G B$ you need to turn $A$, which is a left $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module, into a right $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module. The way you do this is by acting by $g^{-1}$, not by $g$. So $A \otimes_G B$ is given by identifying $g^{-1} a \otimes b = a \otimes gb$. This is equivalent to identifying $a \otimes b = ga \otimes gb$, which is precisely taking coinvariants wrt the diagonal action of $G$ on $A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B$.